# Ansible variable null

Tags: linux, variables, ansible, pid

I have issue with playbook. I have two VMs in my inventory file. Ansible is registering variable form one VM while it is not from the second one

Playbook:

```
- name: Getting dsmcad_DAY PID
  shell: pgrep dsmcad_DAY
  register: pid
  failed_when: "pid.rc not in [ 0, 1 ]"
- name: show out
  debug: 
   msg: "{{ pid }}"
```

error:

```
TASK [show out] *************************************************************************************
ok: [vm00008197] => {
    "msg": ""
}
ok: [vm00008001] => {
    "msg": "45651"
```

When i start this command manually on VMs output is fine.

```
[root@vm00008001 bin]# pgrep dsmcad_DAY
45651


[root@vm00008197 bin]# pgrep dsmcad_DAY
3339
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `pgrep` [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) a return value of 1 means no processes matched. So the process doesn't run on the other VM or is named differently.

Also it might be that your user is not allowed to execute this command on the other VM.

Comment: When i start this command manually on VMs output is fine.

[root@vm00008001 bin]# pgrep dsmcad_DAY
45651


[root@vm00008197 bin]# pgrep dsmcad_DAY
3339

Comment: I have used also this 
ps -ef|grep -i dsmcad_DAY | egrep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'

But in playbook it is act the same.

Comment: OK. Does your ansible script also log in and execute as root? How about trying to ssh into your suspect VM and executing the the pgrep directly? E.g. `$ ssh root@vm00008197 "pgrep dsmcad_DAY"`

Comment: i can't ssh as root directly on my env. But pgrep is running ok on my user.

Comment: Well, that would be the easiest debugging step. But if you can't reproduce this problem in simpler conditions then you'll have to resort to adding verbosity to ansible and analyzing the output. Add `-vvvvv` to your ansible client and see if that brings out the culprit.

Comment: can't find anything related in such huge log.

Answer (score 0):

Now i have tried with other command:

```
- name: Getting dsmcad_DAY PID
  shell: ps -e | grep dsmcad_DAY | awk '{print $1}'
  register: pid_pid
  failed_when: "pid_pid.rc not in [ 0, 1 ]"
- name: show out
  debug:
   var: pid_pid
```

output:

```
TASK [Getting dsmcad_DAY PID] ***********************************************************************
changed: [vm00008197]

TASK [show out] *************************************************************************************
ok: [vm00008197] => {
    "pid_pid": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
        },
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "ps -e | grep dsmcad_DAY | awk '{print $1}'",
        "delta": "0:00:00.023229",
        "end": "2021-01-26 15:12:07.467985",
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-01-26 15:12:07.444756",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```